# CGI Information Disclosure Issue

Tags: twisted

I have a vulnerability scan that is showing that a server running TwistedWeb/2.5.0 on a port is subject to a, "Multiple Web Servers finger CGI Information Disclosure Vulnerability."  We have verified that the actual "Finger" service is not running, and I personally do not believe it to be related to the "Finger" service.  My question is does anyone know of an issue that exists in  TwistedWeb on this topic?  I have searched the tickets on the site page and have looked through posts here on StackOverflow but have not seen anything that helps to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Twisted 2.5.0 is 4 years old at this point.  It's no longer being supported by the developers at twistedmatrix.com.  It may well have bugs.  Please upgrade.

Comment: I appreciate your comments Glyph.... currently though in the org that I am in it is very difficult to upgrade software due to the amount of custom apps we have.  I am just trying to get information on this and will take this and see if it helps.

Comment: I wish I could be more helpful.  To be clear, I do not know of any such issue, and I suspect that the scanner is mis-identifying it.  But, nobody cares about 2.5.0 any more.  Even if you can't upgrade your actual production environment though, you may want to test with more recent versions.  If you discover that the same issue still exists with more recent versions, you might motivate a fix for a more recent version, which you could backport yourself :).